optional (type ExampleType = xxx) for a trait in rust macro
I want to have a macro, help me generate traits, where the associate type ExtraData will be assigned to unit type if not given.
pub trait TestTrait {
    type ExtraData;
    fn test(&self, _state: &Self::ExtraData) {}
    fn test_a(&self, _state: Self::ExtraData) {}
}

pub struct Data;

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! type_or_unit {
    () => { () };
    ($name:ty) => { $name };
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! expand {
    {
        pub struct $example_type:ident;

        impl TestTrait for $example_type1:ident {
            $(type ExtraData = $extra_state:ty;)?
            $($impls:tt)*
        }
    } => {
        pub struct $example_type;

        impl TestTrait for $example_type1 {
            type ExtraData = $crate::type_or_unit! {$( $extra_state )?};
            $($impls)*
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    expand!{
        pub struct Test;

        impl TestTrait for Test {
            type ExtraData = ();
        }
    }
}

The rust macro cannot expand since:
error: local ambiguity when calling macro `expand`: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs tt ('impls') or 1 other option.
  --> src/main.rs:41:13
   |
41 |             type ExtraData = ();

Why does this happen and how to solve the issue?

This feel like a weird way to use declarative macro. You can get around the problem by, instead of matching the pattern at type_or_unit!, match it directly on expand!, that mean make two pattern block, one with type ExtraData = $extra_state:ty; and one without.
However, It will nice if you elabrate on what are you trying to achieve, why your type definition is inside the macro pattern matching? If all the method is already implemented in the trait, why not just take the type and extra data type. If you need to manually implement some function inside the trait, why choose to write a macro to generate 1 line of code.
Why not
pub trait TestTrait {
    type ExtraData;
    fn test(&self, _state: &Self::ExtraData) {}
    fn test_a(&self, _state: Self::ExtraData) {}
}

macro_rules! impl_TestTrait {
    ($t:ty, $extra:ty) => {
        impl TestTrait for $t {
            type ExtraData = $extra;
        }
    };
    ($t:ty) => {
        impl_TestTrait!($t, ());
    }
}

struct Test1;
impl_TestTrait!(Test1, i32);

struct Test2;
impl_TestTrait!(Test2);

fn main() {}

cargo expand
#![feature(prelude_import)]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::rust_2021::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
pub trait TestTrait {
    type ExtraData;
    fn test(&self, _state: &Self::ExtraData) {}
    fn test_a(&self, _state: Self::ExtraData) {}
}
struct Test1;
impl TestTrait for Test1 {
    type ExtraData = i32;
}
struct Test2;
impl TestTrait for Test2 {
    type ExtraData = ();
}
fn main() {}

A get around way base on your idea
pub trait TestTrait {
    type ExtraData;
    fn test(&self, _state: &Self::ExtraData) {}
    fn test_a(&self, _state: Self::ExtraData) {}
}

pub struct Data;

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! expand {
    {
        pub struct $example_type:ident;

        impl TestTrait for $example_type1:ident {
            type ExtraData = $extra_state:ty;
            $($impls:tt)*
        }
    } => {
        pub struct $example_type;

        impl TestTrait for $example_type1 {
            type ExtraData = $extra_state;
            $($impls)*
        }
    };
    {
        pub struct $example_type:ident;

        impl TestTrait for $example_type1:ident {
            $($impls:tt)*
        }
    } => {
        pub struct $example_type;

        impl TestTrait for $example_type1 {
            type ExtraData = ();
            $($impls)*
        }
    }
}

expand!{
    pub struct Test1;
    
    impl TestTrait for Test1 {
        type ExtraData = i32;
    }
}
expand!{
    pub struct Test2;
    
    impl TestTrait for Test2 {
    }
}

cargo expand
#![feature(prelude_import)]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::rust_2021::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
pub trait TestTrait {
    type ExtraData;
    fn test(&self, _state: &Self::ExtraData) {}
    fn test_a(&self, _state: Self::ExtraData) {}
}
pub struct Data;
pub struct Test1;
impl TestTrait for Test1 {
    type ExtraData = i32;
}
pub struct Test2;
impl TestTrait for Test2 {
    type ExtraData = ();
}
fn main() {}

